# Cannot make chat bubble after second without arrow also the time setting with text

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, whatsapp

Hello i cannot make chat bubble for one message with arrow and after that without arrow until the other will send message like in WhatsApp messages screen also I am not able to do the mechanism for timing and text to be shown in same row while message characters are more it will move to second line as shown in screenshot. Please anyone who have make any chat app share its solution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIF1D.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please write your answer here beacuse attached image is showing itself that i need code to do this like whatsapp bubble feature(first message show arrow and second third etc dont have and time is showing almost near to text while double line it move to below) i dont know i can do this from design or program

Comment: Actully i think most of developers don't have answer here may be some are much experienced  may share their thoughts or any previous developed chat can understand this.